# iOS Accelerometer-Based Gesture Recognition

Tags: iphone, ios6, accelerometer, gesture-recognition

I want to create a project that reads the user's gesture (accelerometer-based) and recognise it, I searched a lot but all I found was too old, I neither have problems in classifying nor in recognition, I will use 1 dollar recogniser or HMM, I just want to know how to read the user's gesture using the accelerometer.

Is the accelerometer data (x,y,z values) enough or should i use other data with it like Attitude data (roll, pitch, yaw), Gyro data or magnitude data, I don't even understand anyone of them so explaining what does these sensors do will be useful.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally i did it, i used `userAcceleration` data ***which is device acceleration due to device excluding gravity***, i found a lot of people use the normal acceleration data and do a lot of math to remove gravity from it, now it's already done by iOS 6 in `userAcceleration`.

And i used 1$ recognizer which is a 2D recongnizer (i.e. point(5, 10), no Z).
Here's a link for [1$ recognizer](http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/), there's a c++ version of it in the downloads section.

Here are the steps of my code...

1. Read `userAcceleration` data with frequancy 50 HZ.
2. Apply low pass filter on it.
3. Take a point into consideration only if its x or y values are greater than 0.05 to reduce noise. 
   (Note: The next step depends on  your code and on the recognizer you use).
4. Save x and y points into array.
5. Create a 2D path from this array.
6. Send this path to the recognizer to weather train it or recongize it.

Here's my code...

```
@implementation MainViewController {
    double previousLowPassFilteredAccelerationX;
double previousLowPassFilteredAccelerationY;
double previousLowPassFilteredAccelerationZ;

    CGPoint position;
    int numOfTrainedGestures;
    GeometricRecognizer recognizer;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    previousLowPassFilteredAccelerationX = previousLowPassFilteredAccelerationY = previousLowPassFilteredAccelerationZ = 0.0;

    recognizer = GeometricRecognizer();

    //Note: I let the user train his own gestures, so i start up each time with 0 gestures
    numOfTrainedGestures = 0;
}

#define kLowPassFilteringFactor 0.1
#define MOVEMENT_HZ 50
#define NOISE_REDUCTION 0.05

- (IBAction)StartAccelerometer
{
    CMMotionManager *motionManager = [CMMotionManager SharedMotionManager];
    if ([motionManager isDeviceMotionAvailable])
    {
        [motionManager setDeviceMotionUpdateInterval:1.0/MOVEMENT_HZ];
        [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                       withHandler: ^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
         {
             CMAcceleration lowpassFilterAcceleration, userAcceleration = motion.userAcceleration;

             lowpassFilterAcceleration.x = (userAcceleration.x * kLowPassFilteringFactor) + (previousLowPassFilteredAccelerationX * (1.0 - kLowPassFilteringFactor));
             lowpassFilterAcceleration.y = (userAcceleration.y * kLowPassFilteringFactor) + (previousLowPassFilteredAccelerationY * (1.0 - kLowPassFilteringFactor));
             lowpassFilterAcceleration.z = (userAcceleration.z * kLowPassFilteringFactor) + (previousLowPassFilteredAccelerationZ * (1.0 - kLowPassFilteringFactor));

             if (lowpassFilterAcceleration.x > NOISE_REDUCTION || lowpassFilterAcceleration.y > NOISE_REDUCTION)
                 [self.points addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f,%.2f", lowpassFilterAcceleration.x, lowpassFilterAcceleration.y]];

             previousLowPassFilteredAccelerationX = lowpassFilterAcceleration.x;
             previousLowPassFilteredAccelerationY = lowpassFilterAcceleration.y;
             previousLowPassFilteredAccelerationZ = lowpassFilterAcceleration.z;


             // Just viewing the points to the user
             self.XLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"X : %.2f", lowpassFilterAcceleration.x];
             self.YLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Y : %.2f", lowpassFilterAcceleration.y];
             self.ZLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Z : %.2f", lowpassFilterAcceleration.z];
         }];
    }
    else NSLog(@"DeviceMotion is not available");
}


- (IBAction)StopAccelerometer
{
    [[CMMotionManager SharedMotionManager] stopDeviceMotionUpdates];

    // View all the points to the user
    self.pointsTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d\n\n%@", self.points.count, [self.points componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"]];

    // There must be more that 2 trained gestures because in recognizing, it gets the closest one in distance
    if (numOfTrainedGestures > 1) {
        Path2D path = [self createPathFromPoints]; // A method to create a 2D path from pointsArray
        if (path.size()) {
            RecognitionResult recongnitionResult = recognizer.recognize(path);
            self.recognitionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s Detected with Prob %.2f !", recongnitionResult.name.c_str(),
                                      recongnitionResult.score];
        } else self.recognitionLabel.text = @"Not enough points for gesture !";
    }
    else self.recognitionLabel.text = @"Not enough templates !";

    [self releaseAllVariables];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code sample. Which cpp library did you use and do you have a full example? This would very helpful.

Comment: @Zabady +1 for posting back. I just have a few questions. Could you explain a little how we derive the lowPassFilter? In addition, I am getting all negative values for roll, yaw and pitch accelerations. Is this normal? If so, how would we calculate acceleration rate based on these negative values? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is awesome! What product did you develop this for?